# Google Admin SDK deleting all phone numbers for a user

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Using the admin sdk is it possible to delete all the phone numbers for a particular user using the C# library?
I wish to delete all the phone numbers a user has i.e work, work_fax and work_mobile.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to delete most but not all phone numbers via the admin sdk (If there exists only one phone number, you won't be able to delete that last phone number).  A bug report has been triaged internally.